# Import plot from Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I created the following plot in Gnuplot by fitting a gaussian curve to some data.
In Gnuplot it looks like this: [image: plot in Gnuplot]

It doesn't look perfect but that is totally fine.

I used

```
set terminal latex
set output "output.tex"
replot
```

to create a .tex file which I included in LaTeX by using

```
 \include{output}
```

but when I import it into my LaTeX document in TeXstudio it looks like this
[image: plot in TeXstudio]

How can I make the plot look better? I couldn't make the markers for the data points disappear nor could I change the fit from dots to a line. Since it looks completely different in Gnuplot I don't really know what I am doing wrong. I tried using stuff like "with dots" etc. but then I don't have any errorbars at all.

Comment: I think the latex terminal uses the `picture` environment to generate the plot, but this is very limited. Try using the `epslatex` terminal instead. This creates an eps image, and uses the `picture` environment to add labels etc. It produces much better results.

Answer (score 2):

I like using the `cairolatex` terminal for `gnuplot`.  This is similar to the `epslatex` terminal because it generates a picture without any labels and an accompanying TeX file which includes the picture and writes the labels on top.  The `cairolatex` terminal is superior to the `epslatex` terminal because it allows to save the picture as PDF instead of EPS which then does not need shell-escaping for conversion before including.

In a `gnuplot` file you'd use it as follows:

```gnuplot
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot

set terminal cairolatex pdf
set output 'plot.tex'

set format '$%g$'

set xlabel '$x$ in mm'
set ylabel '$N$' rotate by 0

set samples 1000

set yrange [-.1:1.1]

plot exp(-x**2) title '$\exp(-x^2)$'
```

And in the LaTeX document you simply include the output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\input{plot.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The plot I showed above is not very sophisticated but you can do really nice things with `cairolatex`.  [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cy44f.png) for an example from a document of mine.